# Binding angularjs to MVC C# model array

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

The MVC model contains an array of VCQuestion objects named Questions. (See the definition at the bottom of the code block.) I'm trying to get the following radio button to update the answer field in Question[1]. When the user clicks one of the radio buttons, line 19 in the code block displays the value of the button clicked, but in UpdateOverallRisk(ValuationCheckModel model) in the MVC controller, model does not contain the updated value. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<td>{{ valuationcheck.Questions[1].question }}</td>
<td align="center">
    <input type="radio"
           ng-model="valuationcheck.Questions[1].answer"
           ng-change="updateOverallRisk()"
           value="Yes" />
</td>
<td align="center">
    <input type="radio"
           ng-model="valuationcheck.Questions[1].answer"
           ng-change="updateOverallRisk()"
           value="No" />
</td>
<td align="center">
    <input type="radio"
           ng-model="valuationcheck.Questions[1].answer"
           ng-change="updateOverallRisk()"
           value="N/A" />
    <span>{{ valuationcheck.Questions[1].answer }}</span>
</td>
```

In angularjs controller:

```
$scope.updateOverallRisk = function (model) {
    $http.post('/Products/UpdateOverallRisk', $scope.valuationcheck)
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.data.Status !== "OK") {
                showErrorAlert("Error handling question");
            }
        });
}
```

In MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateOverallRisk(ValuationCheckModel model)
{
    model.CalculateOverallRisk();
    return Json(new { Status = "OK" });
}


// In MVC model:
public class VCQuestion
{
    public int id;
    public string question;
    public string answer;
    public string riskLevelIfNo;
    public int actualRiskLevel;
}
public VCQuestion[] Questions = new VCQuestion[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
```

Paired down version of the MVC model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Comp.Data.Entities.Orders.Products
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ValuationCheckModel
    {
        private const int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 57;

        public string OverallRisk = "Low";

        public class VCQuestion
        {
            public int id;
            public string question;
            public string answer;
            public string riskLevelIfNo;
            public int actualRiskLevel;
        }

        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        public VCQuestion[] Questions = new VCQuestion[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];

        public ValuationCheckModel()
        {
            //Questions = new VCQuestion[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
            Questions[0] = new VCQuestion()
            {
                id = 1,
                question = "This is question one.",
                answer = "",
                riskLevelIfNo = "Moderate",
                actualRiskLevel = 0
            };
            Questions[1] = new VCQuestion()
            {
                id = 2,
                question = "This is question two.",
                answer = "",
                riskLevelIfNo = "Low",
                actualRiskLevel = 0
            };

            OverallRisk = "Low";
        }

        public void CalculateOverallRisk()
        {
            var total = 0;

            foreach (var question in Questions)
            {
                if (question.answer != "No") continue;
                if (question.riskLevelIfNo == "Moderate")
                    total += 1;
                else if (question.riskLevelIfNo == "High")
                    total += 2;
            }

            if (total > 5)
                OverallRisk = "High";
            else if (total > 2)
                OverallRisk = "Moderate";
            else
                OverallRisk = "Low";
        }

        public static ValuationCheckModel Get(Guid orderGuid)
        {
            ValuationCheckModel model = null;

            model = new ValuationCheckModel();
            model.PopulateWithOrderData(orderId);

            return model;
        }

        private void PopulateWithOrderData(Int32 orderId)
        {
            OrderDetail ordDetail = OrderDetail.Get(orderId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ordDetail == null) return;
            this.OrderId = orderId;
            this.ClientName = ordDetail.Order.Client.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: The code seems good. If you console.log `$scope.valuationcheck` right before the post, it's updated?

Comment: I tried consoling out $scope.valuationcheck.Questions[0].answer. See the code fragment below. (The model argument was a mistake -- it's not needed -- but it didn't affect anything.)
    $scope.updateOverallRisk = function () {
        console.log($scope.valuationcheck.Questions[0].answer);
        $http.post('/Products/UpdateOverallRisk', $scope.valuationcheck)
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.data.Status !== "OK") {
                    showErrorAlert("Error handling question");
                }
            });
    }

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment -- I was trying to edit it and ran out of time. The correct value is printed to the console. When I check the value of the model argument in UpdateOverallRisk(ValuationCheckModel model), it does NOT contain the new value for answer. It does, however, contain other changed values. For some reason, the model that is passed to UpdateOverallRisk in the MVC controller contains the updated data for the simple values, but not for the array.

Comment: Can you post your `ValuationCheckModel `?

Comment: Sure. I added it to the code section above. I cut out stuff that I was sure was unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It was a trivial mistake. When I created the Question class, I neglected to define the fields with getters and setters. Once I made that correction, angular had no problem passing the array to MVC. Here's the original class and the corrected version:

```
[Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public int id;
    public string question;
    public string answer;
    public string riskLevelIfNo;
    public int actualRiskLevel;
}

[Serializable]
public class Question
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string riskLevelIfNo { get; set; }
    public int actualRiskLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks everybody for your efforts.